# Sul significato di 'tonto' in 'bollo tonto'

Tags: word-meaning

In un atto amministrativo degli anni '60 ho letto che la comunicazione richiesta doveva essere prodotta con 'bollo tonto'.

Presumo 'tonto' significhi 'annullato', però non trovo riferimenti al riguardo.

Qualcuno mi aiuti, non posso vivere con questa lacuna.

Comment: Non è che è scritto ***bollo tondo*** ? http://it.istruzione.scuola.narkive.com/YvkwmKID/tmbro-tondo

Comment: Ho letto bene. Era 'tonto'. Io avevo anche pensato a un errore per 'tonso', come contrario di 'intonso' (cioè pulito, quindi non annullato), @Josh61.

Comment: E non potrebbe essere un errore di battitura?

Comment: “Bollo tondo” è una locuzione abbastanza usuale: anch'io penserei più a un errore di stampa o battitura che a un uso unico di “tonto”.

Comment: Nell'amministrazione italiana, il “bollo tondo” è un timbro metallico che dà valore legale ai documenti su cui è impresso. Può essere a secco (in rilievo) o, più comunemente, a umido (con inchiostro). Tipico esempio, il bollo che si imprime sulla tessera elettorale dopo la votazione. Propendo per il refuso.

Comment: +1 per il refuso.

Comment: La mia risposta non ti ha convinto?

Comment: @Walter Se la domanda è a me la risposta è: generalmente preferisco accettare una risposta quando ce ne sono almeno due.

Comment: Come diceva Ferrini: "non capisco ma mi adeguo"

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Si tratta molto probabilmente di un fenomeno di [ipercorrezione](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipercorrezione) da parte di un parlante di uno di quei dialetti italiani nei quali si ha sonorizzazione delle consonanti sorde dopo nasale e dopo *l*, ovvero *nt*→*nd*, *mp*→*mb*, eccetera. I dialetti che hanno questa caratteristica appartengono al gruppo dei [dialetti italiani mediani](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialetti_italiani_mediani) (con la notevole eccezione del [romanesco](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialetto_romanesco)) e al gruppo dei [dialetti italiani meridionali](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialetti_italiani_meridionali).

In altre parole, l'impiegato che ha scritto *bollo tonto* ha pensato che *bollo tondo* fosse la pronuncia dialettale di quello che aveva in mente (il timbro tondo a secco o a inchiostro usato per vidimare documenti e per scopi simili), e ha cercato di risalire alla forma scritta "in buon italiano".

Ho visto un'ipercorrezione molto simile con i miei occhi in un commissariato di polizia di Roma negli anni '80: la libera trascrizione dattiloscritta di un mio resoconto aveva prodotto l'espressione *all'orquanto* (sic).